# Continuous families of polyhedra as weighted combinations of basis polyhedra

Tags: reference-request, polyhedra

I saw the following figure in a Chemical Engineering article 'Catalysis on faceted noble-metal nanocrystals: both shape and size matter', Shuifen Xie, Sang-Il Choi, Xiaohu Xia and Younan Xia, Current Opinion in Chemical Engineering 2013, 2:142-150.[image]

It represents a "continuous" family of polyhedra as weighted combinations of a cube, an octahedron and a rhombic dodecahedron (in fact, they consider discrete steps, in the spirit of cristallography).

Beyond the interest of seeing mathematics, and in particular 3D geometry, used in an applied context, I haven't been able to find mathematical works that consider this representation or an analogous one (spherical representation, or a more abstract one, using continuous groups ?).

My question is thus: has somebody ever seen any mathematical work connected to this representation ?

---

Edit (January 16th, 2018): I have found a complete study (though it only deals with convex polyhedra) in the very interesting book by Peter R.  Cromwell named "Polyhedra" (Cambridge ed. 1997) ; I will not give details, but I advise strongly to look at it, with for ex. the following self-speaking topological representation in two figures and one table. (note the central rôle of n°5 = icosahedron).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This picture, centered on the great rhombicosidodecahedron, is extracted (page 15) from an article on the work of Haresh Lalvani in a 1980 issue of this interesting [magazine](http://www-iri.upc.es/people/ros/StructuralTopology/WholeIssues/st6-ocr.pdf).

Related :

Wythoffian operation in
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_solid)

(http://blog.physicsworld.com/2012/07/26/diy-build-a-particle-kit/)

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterman_polyhedron)

(https://www.redbubble.com/fr/people/alliweasley/works/15927513-polyhedral-relations)

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_4-polytope#History_of_discovery)

Comment: There is not much to be seen. Besides, you see yourself this thing is not _really_ continuous. It is just planes with certain Miller indices, plus a peculiar choice of crystal faces that allows for non-convex polyhedra (which by default should not be there). We can make it truly continuous, say, if we limit ourselves to the faces (100), (110) , and (111), and play with their distances from the origin. Still, the math is pretty trivial.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Thanks for your insightful comment.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Please have a look at my Edit of this question.

Comment: That's an interesting development, albeit hardly related to the previous question. As for hierarchical representations, I'm more used to think of a tree of symmetry groups and their subgroups, which kinda puts forward the role of $T$ as the largest common subgroup of $O$ and $I$. The various polyhedra are merely fruits on the branches of the said tree.